# Run Elasticsearch 5.2 on 2 machines but in the same cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

i want to run Elasticsearch on two servers in the same cluster.
The Problem is : I can't connect the 2 servers on elasticsearch. I mean i can't get the 2 nodes on the same cluster.
can somebody tell me if my Configuration in the elasticsearch.yml  is right and

Sever 1:

```
cluster.name: MyData
node.name: Node_1
network.host: '192.160.122.4'
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.160.122.4","192.160.122.3"]
```

Server2:

```
cluster.name: MyData
node.name: Node_2
network.host: '192.160.122.3'
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.160.122.4","192.160.122.3"]
```

what i need to change it ?
Thanks

to the Logs:
Log of server 1:

```
[2017-03-21T10:38:18,859][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Node_1]     
initialized
[2017-03-21T10:38:18,906][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Node_1]           
starting ...
[2017-03-21T10:38:19,764][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [Node_1]    
publish_address {192.160.122.4:9300}, bound_addresses {192.160.122.4:9300}
[2017-03-21T10:38:19,764][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [Node_1] bound 
or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing 
bootstrap checks
[2017-03-21T10:38:22,899][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [Node_1] 
new_master {Master-Node_1}{4ZEftg6TRCOJqE0kEv-Mrg}{MYrWUFABQ5OOT0US73j13w}
{192.160.122.4}{192.160.122.4:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master 
([0] 
nodes joined)
[2017-03-21T10:38:22,950][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [Node_1] 
publish_address {192.160.122.4:9200}, bound_addresses {192.160.122.4:9200}
[2017-03-21T10:38:22,997][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Node_1] started
[2017-03-21T10:38:23,948][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [Node_1] 
recovered [5] indices into cluster_state
[2017-03-21T10:38:32,357][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [Node_1] 
Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards 
started [[node_1][4]] ...]).
```

Log of Server2:

```
[2017-03-21T11:55:57,277][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Node_2] initialized
[2017-03-21T11:55:57,293][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Node_2] starting ...
[2017-03-21T11:56:01,099][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [Node_2] publish_address {192.160.122.3:9300}, bound_addresses {192.160.122.3:9300}
[2017-03-21T11:56:01,115][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [Node_2] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2017-03-21T11:56:01,115][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [Node_2] node validation exception
bootstrap checks failed
JVM is using the client VM [Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM] but should be using a server VM for the best performance
[2017-03-21T11:56:01,146][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Node_2] stopping ...
[2017-03-21T11:56:01,193][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Node_2] stopped
[2017-03-21T11:56:01,193][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Node_2] closing ...
[2017-03-21T11:56:01,240][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Node_2] closed
```

Comment: What do you get in the logs of each node?

Comment: @Val: thanks for the answer.  i updated  my question with logs

Comment: Your second node fails to start, that's why it cannot join the cluster. Do you have the exact same Java install on both nodes?

Comment: on server1 i have Java version  jdk1.8.0_121 and on the server2 i have Java version  jre1.8.0_51.
PS: other poject of ES same version and without any change of configuration of file elasticsearch.yml are working fine.

Comment: You need to install a JDK on server2 (not a JRE), that's why the node is not starting.

Comment: @Val : You are right the problem was Java version. but i get now an other Error: [2017-03-21T16:23:30,876][INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [Master-Node_2] failed to send join request to master [{Node_1}{4ZEftg6TRCOJqE0kEv-Mrg}{cQWfrRbKQk6jxRxXQayAAA}{192.160.122.4}{192.160.122.4:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[Master-Node_1][192.160.122.4:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: ConnectTransportException[[Node_2][192.160.122.3:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: IOException[Connection timed out: no further information: 192.160.122.3/192.160.122.3:9300]; ] from Server2

Comment: i resolved this problem with steps:
1) i created on each server a new file with ES program
2) i replaced in file Config "elasticsearch.yml" with the old  "elasticsearch.yml" included my configuration what i posted above.
3) i ensure that the Connexion working fine. yes It's. The first server has detected the second server.
4) i copypasted the data file with my database on the first server
5) the second server got automatically all database from the first server.
i hope that this solution  will help the new generation of programmers.
Thanks @Val for your advice.